# How can I delete commas from a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby, string, substitution

I have the string `"12,34,56,789,George Carter,4"`. I want the output to look like:

```
12 34 56 789 George Carter 4
```

My current code is not working for me. I've tried:

```
str = "12,34,56,789,George Carter,4"
str.split(",")
```

Comment: Note that you aren't really "deleting" commas in your example. For that, you could just use String#delete. Instead, you're substituting or translating them into some other character.

Comment: Welcome. This is a very elementary question that you could solve yourself by reading a tutorial, searching (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421) or by reading [the String documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html). We don't want to discourage you, but programming involves a lot of researching to learn new stuff so you'll want to get really good at that.

Answer (score 9):

### Use String's Character-Translation Method

Use [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-tr) (the string translate method) to translate one or more characters within a Ruby string. For example:

```
str = "12,34,56,789,George Carter,4".tr(',', ' ')
#=> "12 34 56 789 George Carter 4"
```

There are certainly other ways to do this, but this way works well with your given example and may be semantically clearer about your intent than other techniques. In addition, String#tr is often the right choice when you want to translate sets of characters rather than to replace substrings.

Answer (score 3):

```
str.gsub(',', ' ')
# => "12 34 56 789 George Carter 4"
```

will replace commas in str with a space. `.split` is used to split a string into an array. You could use it like so:

```
str.split(','),join(' ')
# => "12 34 56 789 George Carter 4"
```

But its more convoluted and slower.

Answer (score 0):

You have already split the string around comma, now join using spaces.

```
str.split(",").join(' ')
```